# How can I prevent unprivileged users from accessing /etc/passwd, /etc/group, etc

Tags: permissions, users, groups, passwd-file

As the title suggests, I have a multi user environment, and in the interest of protecting privacy, I'd really like to be able to restrict users access to some of these publicly viewable files that give away info about other users.

If I restrict access to `/etc/passwd` with `0640`, things stop working for that user.

If I add that user to a restrictive ACL, things stop working for that user.

I'd really like to avoid kicking unprivileged-users in to a jail if I can. I just want user privacy to be respected on a shared server. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't quite understand what privacy you wish to protect. "Hubert is in the Fancy group" doesn't seem personal or useful. Can you please clarify a bit?

Comment: as mentioned in https://serverfault.com/questions/154345/how-do-you-block-etc-passwd-file
these files have to be readable.

Comment: @user535733 - For example, my intention was to use a clients domain name on a web server, as their username. So, `jesus-is-our-saviour--com`, or `milfs-like-to-have-fun--net`, etc... If clients can just `less /etc/passwd` and see that other clients we're dealing with don't fit with their morals, then it could cost clients, alternatively, competitors could get an account to simply see our client list... I guess I'll have to look at another naming scheme for clients? Unless there's any other ideas?

Comment: Use docker and give each client a separate vm

Comment: @Panther - I'm not sure what you mean. Docker creates containers that sit on top of the kernel. VM's are self contained computers, which mean having an individual OS, libraries, applications, configurations, etc., all running, which will not only take up a lot of storage resources, but also a lot of system resources, and be a nightmare to monitor and maintain.

Comment: Ypu cam not jave the privacy ypu want without isolation. Users need to jave ro access to those files and there are other ways to determine user and site names on your server. Docker is lightest and easiest

Comment: At this point I figure just having undescriptive usernames is the way to go. I realise I could have special ssh login shells, using LXC, but that's a lot more trouble than it's worth IMO. Saying that, what other methods are there of obtaining usernames? I realise that site names can be obtained from the vhosts, but they're already locked down to the apache user/group (which users aren't a part of)..?